# Connecting the PyDev debugger to a remote computer running a different OS

Tags: debugging, eclipse

We develop software, which constantly needs to be debugged on both Linux and Windows. The way I would like to do this is to have an option in Eclipse (PyDev) saying "Debug this application on the remote Linux server". I then want the option to execute the code line-by-line.

Does such a feature exist in Eclipse? If it does not exist in Eclipse, what is the recommended approach to do such a thing? I have thought about installing Eclipse also on the Linux server, but then I have the extra work of configuring and maintaining several eclipse setups.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html ?

One thing you cannot escape from right now is having the sources for the debugger in the platform you want to run... (although you don't need eclipse itself there, at least you need the contents of org.python.pydev.debug/pysrc there, so, maybe you can create your script which will copy those from a 'central' location you keep updated, or if you have a shared folder, just add that network folder to your pythonpath).